# FileNotFoundException:(No such file or directory) FileOutputStream

Tags: android, file, object, save, fileoutputstream

I am trying to save an object to a file using FileOutputStream

keep getting an error of FileNotFoundException

this is my code -

```
    public static Library getFavoritesLibrary() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    // read object from file
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("favlibrary.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Library result = (Library) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();

    return result;
}

public static void setFavoritesLibrary(Station station) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {


    Library beforeLibrary = getFavoritesLibrary();
    ArrayList<Station> favStations = beforeLibrary.getStations();
    if (favStations.contains(station)){
        favStations.remove(station);
    } else {
        favStations.add(station);
    }


    // write object to file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("favlibrary.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(beforeLibrary);
    oos.close();

}
```

tried mkdirs() - it sais that this is ignored always...

tried this as well -

```
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "favlibrary.ser");
```

I'm asking for permissions as well...

what should I do?

Comment: `tried this as well -

        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "favlibrary.ser");`. Good idea. But that statement does nothing. How did you use it?

Comment: `'m asking for permissions as well...` What kind of permissions? But for what you are doing you do not need any permission.

Comment: `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("favlibrary.ser");` FIleOutputStream expects a full path. Indeed that should be `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), "favlibrary.ser"));`

Comment: `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("favlibrary.ser");`. Here also use full path.

Comment: still, now it has a full path, and it shows on logcat but still says that the file/folder doesn't exist

Comment: File/folder? You only try to write a file. Which folder? Please adapt your code here so it represents that what you have.

Comment: `if(!getFilesDir.exists()) Toast(........);`. Add that statement too please.